# PHP dropdown with <select> using variables 'id'

Tags: php, html, select, dropdown

I did many HTML dropdown (which generate select tags etc) with PHP scripts for different HTML files. Previously, I had as many dropdown scripts as there are HTML files. But now, I would like to have one script for all HTML files. For this, I need to have a variable 'id' attribut of the select tag which depend of the parameter of the url of each HTML page. I try to affect the parameter of the url to the 'id' attribut but without results.

Here is the url of one of the web page with a parameter 'name'.
    http://127.0.0.1/projetwebtest/projetweb/indexSuperClass.php?name=superClass

And here is the code of the PHP script where I try to affect the url parameter value to the 'id' attribut.

One way :

```
$opt .= "<select class = 'custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--emerald' id = '<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>' onchange = 'change();'>";
```

Another way :

```
$opt .= "<select class = 'custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--emerald' id = '$_GET['name'];' onchange = 'change();'>";
```

When I try to print with a 'echo' the url parameter $_GET['name'] it works but it doesn't in this case.

How can I affect the url paramter to the 'id' attribut ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is comprised of various uses of " and ' which is causing it to fail. Here's a working example. You can [copy and paste it here](http://phptester.net/) to test it online.

```
   $_GET['name'] = 'SELECT_TEST_ID';

   $opt = '<select class="custom-dropdown__select custom-dropdown__select--emerald" id="' . $_GET['name'] . '" onchange="change();">';

   echo $opt;
```

Sidenote: When you're creating HTML strings like these, and are not using a template engine, try using `'HTML String'` instead of `"HTML String"`, letting you avoid quote hell for HTML attributes.